# Yii2 Kartik-v Editable Column update multiple table cells

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I set up editable column for the GridView in Yii2 with Kartik Editable extension. The problem I am facing is that I cannot find a way to update multiple table cell from one editable column.
The things I did:
**GridView column**

```
[
                    'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                    'attribute'=>'post_title',
                    'editableOptions'=> function ($model, $key, $index) {

                            return [
                                'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
                                'size'=>'sm',
                                'afterInput'=>function ($form, $widget) use ($model, $index) {
                                    return $form->field($model, 'post_description')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Enter post title']);
                                }
                            ];
                        }

                ],
```

By clicking edit post title column it shows edit fields for title and description

**PostsController action**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PostsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
            $postId = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
            $model = Posts::findOne($postId);

            $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);

            $post = [];
            $posted = current($_POST['Posts']);
            $post['Posts'] = $posted;

            if ($model->load($post)) {
                $output = '';
                $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'']);
                $model->save();
            }
            echo $out;
            return;
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

So, when I edit post title and description only post title is saved into database. 
I think it is because current saves only one value

```
$posted = current($_POST['Posts']);
```

What is the proper way to save both 
**$model->post_title** and **$model->post_description** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Ajax editable column. At a time only one value would be sent to the controller.

So the class of `post_title` and `post_description` column must be editable in the view.

This should work everytime you edit those columns.

Also change this

```
if ($model->load($post)) {
    if (isset($model->post_title)){
        // here you can format the value of the attribute
          and display on the screen
             $output = $model->post_title;
    }
    if (isset($model->post_description)){
        $output = $model->post_description;
    } 
    $model->save();
    // Here you send a message that the value has been saved
    $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'Saved']);                
}
```